# WPF TreeView folderbrowser - data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, treeview

I want to show in a WPF TreeView a hierarchical folderbrowser based on on this class:

```
Public Class _Folder
     Public Property Name As String
     Public ReadOnly Property SubFolders As List(Of _Folder) = New List(Of _Folder)()
End Class
```

Loading my Window I create my demodata:

```
Private Sub Test2_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

        Dim lst As New List(Of _Folder)

        Dim str As _Folder = New _Folder()

        str.Name = "Client 1"
        For x = 1 To 10
            Dim y As _Folder = New _Folder With {.Name = "Mandant " & x}
            str.SubFolders.Add(y)
        Next
        lst.Add(str)

        str = New _Folder()
        str.Name = "Client 2"
        For x = 1 To 10
            Dim y As _Folder = New _Folder With {.Name = "Mandant " & x}
            str.SubFolders.Add(y)
        Next
        lst.Add(str)

        tvw.DataContext = lst

    End Sub
```

In XAML I have the following TreeView

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvw" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="798" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

But result is just like this, so no

[image]

Can oneone help me with that?

EDIT:
Changed XAML to

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvw" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="798" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:_Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Name}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

Now the result shows that there exists subfolders, but the subfolder names are not show:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it finally:

**The class:**

```
Public Class _Folder
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property FullPath As String
    Public ReadOnly Property SubFolders As List(Of _Folder) = New List(Of _Folder)()
End Class
```

**The XAML:**

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvw" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="798" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="TreeViewItem.IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:_Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubFolders}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=FullPath}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

**The code:**

```
Dim lstFolders As New List(Of _Folder)
Dim RootFolder As New _Folder

For Each f In _items
    If f.Contains("\\") Then f = f.Replace("\\", ":")
    Dim drive = f.Split(":")(0)
    Dim path = f.Split(":")(1)

    'If String.IsNullOrEmpty(drive) Then Continue For
    RootFolder.Name = drive

    Dim charSeparators As Char() = New Char() {System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}
    Dim pathSplit() As String = path.Split(charSeparators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Dim currentFolder As _Folder = RootFolder
    For Each level In pathSplit
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(level) Then Continue For
        Dim foundFolder = (From x In currentFolder.SubFolders Where x.Name = level Select x).FirstOrDefault
        If foundFolder Is Nothing Then
            foundFolder = New _Folder
            foundFolder.Name = level
            If f.StartsWith(":") Then 'Netzwerkpfad
                foundFolder.FullPath = (f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(level)) & level).Replace(":", "\\")
            Else 'Pfad mit Laufwerksbuchstaben
                foundFolder.FullPath = f.Substring(0, f.IndexOf(level)) & level
            End If
            currentFolder.SubFolders.Add(foundFolder)
        End If
        currentFolder = foundFolder
    Next

Next

lstFolders.Add(RootFolder)

tvw.DataContext = lstFolders
```

**My list(of String) looks like this, it is just a bunch of folders:**

```
c:\temp\freigabe
c:\temp\ftptest
c:\temp\ftptest\testen
c:\temp\in
c:\temp\in - Kopie
c:\temp\in - Kopie\1
c:\temp\in - Kopie\1\yyy
c:\temp\in - Kopie\1\yyy\yyyyy
c:\temp\in - Kopie\2
c:\temp\in2
c:\temp\ipadb
c:\temp\out
c:\temp\out2
c:\temp\Processes2
c:\temp\Processes2\Kassenbelege
c:\temp\Processes2\Kassenbelege\images
c:\temp\Processes2\Posteingang
c:\temp\Processes2\Posteingang\images
c:\temp\Processes2\Rechnungen
c:\temp\Processes2\Rechnungen\images
c:\temp\Processes2\Rechnungen\images\backup
c:\temp\test
```

Answer (score 0):

`HierarchicalDataTemplate.DataType` is supposed to be your data class i.e. `_Folder`, not the GUI object type `TreeViewItem`.

Also, `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource` specifies the child items for the node in question, so you need to change that binding to `{Binding SubFolders}`.

Comment: Hello Mark. I changed both, but now I just get "

(Sammlung)
(Sammlung)
"
as result.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: The only thing wrong was the XAML binding. This one works for me:

```
<TreeView x:Name="tvw" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="798" Margin="10,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:_Folder}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubFolders}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```